# App upload failed because the key was used in other apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I am trying to upload an app to Google Play in *app bundle* format but it is failing with the below error -

`You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload.`

I already have some apps released in the market which are signed with the same keystore (but in apk format).

I want to use the same keystore to sign this app as well. Is this possible without creating a new keystore?

Comment: what unclear is in the error message you are seeing?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Error message is clear but I'm looking for a way where same keystore could be used to sign this app bundle as well.

Comment: while `should` may suggest there's the way, it would be much faster for you to have separate key. If they check the hash, then no matter what the message says you won't pass otherway

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I want to keep same keystore so that the apps can communicate with each other when they need to. Hence new key is not a solution I'm looking for.

Comment: what you want/need is not necessary what you can have. that's the point here.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Are you saying that this is not at all possible? Do you have doc supporting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message indicates that you are signing your App Bundle with a key that is used as an **app signing key** by another of your apps. However the App Bundle should be signed with an **app upload key**. The two shouldn't be mixed.

The definitions of those terms can be found on [this documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB) (see *"Description of keys, artifacts and tools"*).

When you enroll in App Signing by Play, the default is for Play to generate the app signing key. If you want Play to sign the APKs it generates with the same key as another of your app, you have to select **"(Advanced options) Provide the app signing key that Google Play uses for this app"** at the time of enrollment:

[image: Play Console screenshot]

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do we see the apps in the dropdown which are not opted for google play signin?

Comment: No, since Google wouldn't have the key of those. For this use case, you can use one of the options below.